# Passing the answer of Watson Assistant to a variable Python

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I am trying to get the output of Watson Assistant into a variable. So as far as I have searched, i need to get the "output" and "text" part of the json (at first it is a dict, but then we parse it to a json). But I cannot seem to get it:

I have searched in these 2 questions already:[This one for watson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52827947/how-to-print-the-answer-returned-by-ibm-watson-assistant) [This one for parsing the json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306653/python-accessing-nested-json-data)

The code is really simple: accessing to my bot, and inputting "trips". I've taken out the api and workspace, but I have them (obviously).

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    assistant = watson_developer_cloud.AssistantV1(

        iam_apikey='{YOUR API HERE}',
        version='2018-09-20',
        url='https://gateway-syd.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api'
    )

    response = assistant.message(
        workspace_id='{YOUR WORKSPACE HERE}',
        input={
            'text': 'trips'
        }
    ).get_result()
    fullResponse=json.dumps(response, indent=2)
    print(fullResponse)
    print("testing to print the output: ")
    respuesta=json.dumps(response, indent=2)
    #print(respuesta['output'][0]['text'])
    print(respuesta['output']['text'])
```

And the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  "intents": [
  File "C:/Users/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/pruebaMain.py", line 105, in <module>
    {
    print(respuesta['output']['text'])
      "intent": "trips",
TypeError: string indices must be integers
      "confidence": 1
    }
  ],
  "entities": [],
  "input": {
    "text": "trips"
  },
  "output": {
    "generic": [
      {
        "response_type": "text",
        "text": "We got trips to different countries! Type continents to know more!"
      }
    ],
    "text": [
      "We got trips to different countries! Type continents to know more!"
    ],
    "nodes_visited": [
      "node_2_1544696932582"
    ],
    "log_messages": []
  },
  "context": {
    "conversation_id": "{took it out for privacy}",
    "system": {
      "initialized": true,
      "dialog_stack": [
        {
          "dialog_node": "root"
        }
      ],
      "dialog_turn_counter": 1,
      "dialog_request_counter": 1,
      "_node_output_map": {
        "node_2_1544696932582": {
          "0": [
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "branch_exited": true,
      "branch_exited_reason": "completed"
    }
  }
}
testing to print the output: 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So I want to get the answer of "We got trips to different countries! Type continents to know more!". I have read the documentation of the python API and some more info (https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables) of  but can't seem to find anything. I also tried accessing the json variable with `$`but did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to use `json.dumps` here, you can directly use the response JSON returned from the service as shown in the code snippet below

```
import watson_developer_cloud

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assistant = watson_developer_cloud.AssistantV1(

        iam_apikey='APIKEY',
        version='2018-09-20',
        url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api'
    )

    response = assistant.message(
        workspace_id='WORKSPACE_ID',
        input={
            'text': 'trips'
        }
    ).get_result()

    print(response)
    print(response['output']['text'][0])
```

Comment: Thank you! 
So json.dumps "loads" the dict into a json, so I had a string. I am happy with your answer, but what about using `dumps`. What could be done?

Comment: Yes, `json.dumps` returns a String. The response object is already a Dictionary and traversing through a dictionary is pretty easy in Python. Add this code and you will understand the type of the object ```print(type(response))
    jsondumps = json.dumps(response)
    print(type(jsondumps))```